# Can't get ref from componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component

```
export default class ActivityPage extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.textarea = React.createRef();
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.textarea.current.select();
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <textarea defaultValue="the quick brown fox." ref={this.textarea} />
        </div>
      );
   }
}
```

When I go to a route with this component, I get the following error
[image]

I installed 16.3.2 React version.

Comment: It should work fine.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, I know, I found this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmasqk?file=index.js. But I can't understand why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please share the demo that actually don't work.

Comment: Your component works fine for me if I add it to a newly created project from create-react-app

Comment: @Axnyff even he's showing working demo.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, Ok. I will try to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this issue. It was completely my fault. I didn't update the `react-dom` package to 16.3.2 version.

Comment: it's still pretty helpful to the community, in case somebody else will face the problem.